Formatting the data from a FILTER function
So I currently made these three formulas:
=INT(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("/", B115)), LEFT(B115, SEARCH("/", B115) - 1), B115))

=INT(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("/", B115)), RIGHT(B115, LEN(B115) - SEARCH("/", B115)), B115))

=FILTER($D2:$D, $A2:$A = $A9, $E2:$E = $A1)

The data I get from the FILTER is:
6
13
7
23
32
1/15
26

And the intention of the function above the FILTER is that whenever there is a / in the number, it will grab the number on the RIGHT. The way I intend this to work is that whenever the FILTER returns the data, it will be formatted as follows instead:
6
13
7
23
32
15
26

And using the LEFT should return the data as follows:
6
13
7
23
32
1
26

Is there any way to combine the filtered data with one of two features I made above it in the same function?

Try:
=FILTER(--IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT($D2:$D),"/(.+)"),$D2:$D), $A2:$A = $A9, $E2:$E = $A1)

EDIT: Another solution
=FILTER(--REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT($D2:$D),"\d+$"), $A2:$A = $A9, $E2:$E = $A1)

